# Search terms repeated three times when using Google Chrome Omnibar

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

When using the Omnibar (address bar) to search Google, the search term is repeated thrice. The search still works, but it is quite annoying, especially when you want to modify your original query. Any idea why, and how to fix it?

Example: When searching for "test" the following URL is produced:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=test&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&q=test&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&channel=fflb&q=test&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&channel=rcs
```

- Google Chrome (Version 22.0.1229.94), freshly installed
- Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Answer (score 10):

For some reason, the default settings for the google search engine is incorrect. Go to Preferences, Manage Search Engines. Change the URL for the Google (Default) entry

- Old value: https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&q=%s&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&channel=fflb&q=%s&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&channel=rcs
- New value: http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&channel=fflb